# CreateWindow is returning a NULL handle

Tags: c++, createwindow

Alright so I've been sitting here for over 30 mins trying to solve this problem, in "Create Window" it gives me a NULL value unless I have the class name as "LoginClassName" if I use "RegisterClassName" it will return a NULL. I am trying to create a pop-up window and so far its kicking my ass. I create the class the same as LoginClass so I don't really see the problem.

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow) {

MSG msg;
WNDCLASSW LoginClass = { 0 };
wchar_t LoginClassName[] = L"LoginWindow";

LoginClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
LoginClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
LoginClass.hbrBackground = HBRUSH(GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));
LoginClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(hInstance, IDC_ARROW);
LoginClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
LoginClass.lpfnWndProc = LoginWndProc;
LoginClass.hInstance = hInstance;
LoginClass.lpszClassName = LoginClassName;
LoginClass.lpszMenuName =  NULL;
LoginClass.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;

if (!RegisterClass(&LoginClass))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Error", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    return 0;
}

WNDCLASSW RegisterWindowClass = { 0 };

wchar_t RegisterClassName[] = L"Test";

RegisterWindowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
RegisterWindowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
RegisterWindowClass.hbrBackground = HBRUSH(GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));
RegisterWindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(hInstance, IDC_ARROW);
RegisterWindowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
RegisterWindowClass.lpfnWndProc = RegisterWndProc;
RegisterWindowClass.hInstance = hInstance;
RegisterWindowClass.lpszClassName = RegisterClassName;
RegisterWindowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
RegisterWindowClass.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;

if (!RegisterClass(&RegisterWindowClass))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Error", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    return 0;
}

hLoginWindow = CreateWindow(LoginClassName, L"GameLauncher Login", WS_SYSMENU | WS_CAPTION | WS_OVERLAPPED, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 350, 200, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
hRegisterWindow = CreateWindowEx(NULL, RegisterClassName, L"Register Account", WS_SYSMENU | WS_CAPTION | WS_OVERLAPPED, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 350, 200, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

ShowWindow(hLoginWindow, iCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hLoginWindow);

while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

return msg.wParam;
}
```

This is the `WndProc` of the `RegisterClassWindow`:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK RegisterWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

switch (uMessage)
{
    case WM_CREATE: {
        break;
    }

    case WM_DESTROY:{
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
    }

    default:{
    DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMessage, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might try using `return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMessage, wParam, lParam);`.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @BetaCarotin Oh my god, I've been overlooking that for so long. Duh... Thanks!